# Add an index to composite primkary keys in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

Let's suppose that I have three tables:

> Customer (**CustomerID**, dateofbirth, city, address, telephone, sale,
> sex)
>
> Purchase (**CustomerID**, **ItemID**, **date**)
>
> Item (**ItemID**, description, color, price, suppliedby, stock)

So, cutomerID is the primary key for Customer, ItemID for Item, and (CustomerID, ItemID, Date) is the composite primary key for Purchase table.

As far as i know, there is no need to apply index on primary keys (in this case, customerID for table 1 and ItemID for table 3) since mysql does this automatically.

What about composite primary keys?

Should I apply a unique index on the composite pk (CustomerID, ItemID, Date)? or it is preferable to add separate non-unique index on three columns (so, a non unique index on customerID, a non unique index on ItemID and a non unique index on dateID) ?

Consider that these three tables are very rich of data, and many joins are required

Answer (score 1):

A primary key has an associated index. This does not depend on whether your primary key is composite or not.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/primary-key-optimization.html):

> The primary key for a table represents the column **or set of columns** that you use in your most vital queries. It has an **associated index**, for fast query performance.

If you have queries that put conditions on the `Purchase.Date` field, then you *might* get a benefit from a non-unique index on that field alone. But whether this index will be used in an actual query must be verified with [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html). That will give you the final confirmation that indeed that index is used or not. If you find it is not used, then drop it, since an index also comes with an extra overhead cost for every DML update of the concerned table.

Comment: So, the fact that, for example, I have to do many joins between customer and purchase, using "customerID", does nto suggest me to add a non-unique index on CustomerID in the table purchase?

Comment: No, `customerID` is the first field of the composite index, so that index can be used for such a join. But again, the database engine will decide on that when analysing the query and determining the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

The composite primary key on `Purchase` is based on the unique index on `(CustomerID, ItemID, date)`.

This is not equivalent to separate indexes on `(CustomerID)`, `(ItemID)`, and `(Date)`.

Do you need the separate indexes?  Well, for any join from `Purchases` to either `Customers` or `Items`, the index on `Purchases` is not very important -- what is important it the primary key on the reference table.

When would you want secondary indexes?  Probably less for joins and more for filtering.  In particular, I can imagine that filtering on `date` would be important and might be worth an index.

Also, if you have queries such as "Get all items that have not been purchased (say between two dates)", that would often be phrased as:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1 from purchases p where p.itemId = i.itemId);
```

In this case, an index on `Purcahses(itemId)` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, pirmary keys are automatically indexed

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index, for fast query performance.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/primary-key-optimization.html